# Hard time uderstaning async.parallel in node

Tags: node.js, api, express, asynchronous

I have this function in the controller

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user.isPremium == false) {
    // Free user - Single report
    let website = req.body.website0;
    let builtWithCall = `https://api.builtwith.com/free1/api.json?KEY=APIKEY&LOOKUP=${website}`;
    let pagespeedCall = `https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed?url=https://${website}&strategy=mobile&key=APIKEY`;
    // curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed?url=https://georgiancollege.ca&strategy=mobile&key=APIKEY'
    var calls = [];
    calls.push(function(callback) {
      // First call
      https.get(builtWithCall, function(resource) {
        resource.setEncoding('utf8');
        resource.on('data', function(data) {
          // console.log('BuiltWith received', data);
        });
      });
    });
    calls.push(function(callback) {
      // second call
      https.get(pagespeedCall, function(resource) {
        resource.setEncoding('utf8');
        resource.on('data', function(data) {
          // console.log(data);
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
    // Premium user - comparison report
    let websites = [];
  }
  async.parallel(calls, function(err, results) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('async callback ', results);
    res.render('/generated-report', {
      title: 'Report',
      data: {},
    });
  });
});
```

I am trying to run several async API calls at once. The problem is, when I try to run them like this

```
async.parallel(calls, function(err, results) {
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('async callback ', results);
  res.render('/generated-report', {
    title: 'Report',
    data: {},
  });
});
```

the console doesn't log anything.

When I do the console log here though

```
function(callback) {
  // second call
  https.get(pagespeedCall, function(resource) {
    resource.setEncoding('utf8');
    resource.on('data', function(data) {
      // console.log(data);
    });
  });
}
```

it logs the response. The pageSpeed one gets in a weird loop and repeats itself multiple times, but at least it works.

Now what am I doing wrong with the `async.parallel` part? Also what is this callback in `function(callback) {`?

EDIT:

This is the new version of the anonymous function:

```
function(callback) {
  // second call
  var results;
  https.get(pagespeedCall, function(resource) {
    resource.setEncoding('utf8');
    resource.on('data', function(data) {
      results += data;
      // console.log(data);
    });
    resource.on('end', function(data) {
      callback(null, data);
    });
    resource.on('error', function(err) {
      callback(err);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the passed in `callback`. Looking at your one parallel function you are not calling `callback()`. I'll assume your `resource` object has an `end` & `error`

```
function(callback) {
  // second call
  var results;
  https.get(pagespeedCall, function(resource) {
    resource.setEncoding('utf8');
    resource.on('data', function(data) {
       results += data;
      // console.log(data);
    });
    resource.on('end' function() {
      callback(null, results);
    });
    resource.on('error' function(err) {
      callback(err);
    });
  });
}
```

How `async.parallel` works is all the functions called must in turn call the passed in callback function; in your case that is `callback`.
Once each function in the parallel calls callback then and only then will the final function be called, which is the function you defined as `function(err, results) {...}`.

There is one caveat, if in the `callback` call you pass non-null for the first argument then that final function will be called immediately where you should handle that error if it happens.

Comment: I am really confused. Now `console.log(results)` in the async.parallel is returning 2 undefined. At least the call is being made. Any idea what the problem is? I'll edit my post to paste the working version of the function

Comment: you mean the call `console.log('async callback ', results);` is displaying nothing for `results`?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure why

Comment: It's because you either encountered an error and that function is populating the arg `err` or you are not passing data into `results`. It is your job to pass the data using the second argument in the callback. i.e, `callback(null, "Hello World");` now the `result` object will contain `["Hello World"]`

Comment: `resource.on('end', function(data) {
          callback(null, data);
        });`
I have this so far. Is this wrong?

Comment: You tell me. I am unable to answer if the object `resource` has an event emitter named 'end'. before you get over your head. Simply call `callback(null, "Hello World");` at the very top of your function(s) and see if the data is getting passed to `results`. If it is then great, you can start working with the `resource` object to get it's data.

Comment: Yup you were right. Then it's something with the `data` passed into the callback. "Hello world" worked.

Comment: This works.
`resource.on('end', function() {
          callback(null, results);
        });`